# NextJS: Is it possible to hide the locale in URLs for localized routing?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

### The Question

I was wondering if there is any way of having the same visible URL for the client while being able to handle internationalization.

### My use case

- I want my users to have universal access to pages and hide the locales from the URL path. If a user shares a link with another user, the content should be loaded in the preferred language of the current user that opens the page.
- I'm fetching localized data on the server-side with `getServerSideProps` and caching the result with `Cache-Control` for 5-10 minutes. So, passing locale as a query parameter (`?lang=en`, `?lang=ca`, etc) probably won't work as the cached results should be different for different locales.

### What I have done before

- My app was written entirely in React and I'm now moving to Next.js. I used to pass the locale in a URL query parameter like `?lang=en`. I would then store that locale in the `localStorage`, send API requests with the given locale, and change the app's appearance accordingly.
- That used to work fine, but now I want to make use of the server-side rendering and request caching, which makes things more complicated.

---

This seems to be a common use case. Is there any way to handle the internationalization without explicitly changing the URL? Or maybe having one URL at first and then hiding some parts after? Any kind of idea/workaround would be really appreciated!

Comment: Are you using Next.js [Internationalized Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing) or are you routing without it?

Comment: I'd prefer to route without it as it adds a locale in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to get a similar result. So far I haven't found a way to get rid of the local part in the url (I use next-i18next).
But I managed to handle the "content must be loaded in the preferred language of the user opening the page" part with cookie and middleware with the following

```
const url = request.nextUrl.clone();
url.locale = userPreferredLanguage;
url.pathname =
  request.nextUrl.pathname === '/'
    ? `/${userPreferredLanguage}`
    : `/${userPreferredLanguage}${request.nextUrl.pathname}`;
return NextResponse.redirect(url);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Tanguy! I think NextJs provides a specific cookie for that called `NEXT_LOCALE`. Yet, I think it would be impossible to use a public Cache-Control header in this case as the cache is stored for everyone and is not changed per cookie. There was a great answer on a GitHub discussion: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/39746

Comment: @Martin So did the solution from https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/39746#discussioncomment-3434177 work for you? It seems to address exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: Not exactly, the cache is set to vary based on the AcceptLanguage header, which is not changed based on the NEXT_LOCALE cookie. So, the cache is not stored in the CDN properly.

There is another solution - which is to use the AWS CloudFront which allows you to configure the cache based on a specific cookie. Yet, in that case, you might have misconfiguration with Vercel's deployment (which I don't have too much experience with).